# France Schengen Visa; Want to Travel to Italy Next Month

Tags: visas, schengen, france, italy, multiple-entry

I was recently issued a France Schengen Visa (multiple entries); however, I want to travel to Italy next month...will I need to apply for a Spanish Schengen Visa or can I use the France Visa to go to Italy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. It's a Schengen visa which would mean you can go to Italy using it. Even if you couldn't why would you apply for another one with the Spanish Embassy?

Comment: Thanks for your response.

Sorry if I wasn't clear...What I meant was I was issued a Visa by the French Consulate and I'll be traveling to Paris this month, for a week.

After I return home, I would like to go to Italy next month.

I've been doing research and so far what I've read basically says "I need to spend most of my vacation time in the country that issued the visa"

Comment: Further to my original post, I meant an Italian Visa...not Spanish

Answer (score 0):

The Schengen visa is valid for all countries of *l’espace Schengen*; you can use it for entering *l’espace Schengen* at any border. If it has not expired, you are ok. But the national authorities can still refuse you entry for another reason: you are coming from a dangerous country, you have an arrest warrant on your head, etc ;)